# BluetoothAdapter dead object exception

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Sometimes I've got an dead object exception when trying use my `BluetoothAdapter`. How can I check if it is already dead before use? Or should I recreate `BluetoothAdapter` every time in `onResume` for example?

I suppose the reason of that exception is crash of `BluetoothManager`. As the result instances of `BluetoothAdapter` and `BluetoothGattServer` became dead objects and I can no longer use it. Please suggest me some work around this problem. Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

Why not put a receiver on your BluetoothAdapter state actions and do your necessary controls such as for the ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED. If your Adapter is damaged somehow, try to gracefully clean up remaining stuff and just create a new Adapter.